# How does GeoCoordinateWatcher get location C#

Tags: c#, geolocation

I'm currently interested in the way the GeoCoordinateWatcher-class is getting the actual location of my device.
Is it supposed to have a GPS antenna or can I also go with WIFI?
If the WIFI-method is also possible, is it activated by default?

greets

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the sensor's availability on the target device and the `DesiredAccuracy` requested, `GeoCoordinateWatcher` will try to get the position from:

- GPS (higher accuracy)
- Cellular Triangulation
- WiFi Triangulation

`GeoCoordinateWatcher` is an abstraction over how the different sensors work, giving you the freedom to just ask for the current position, without the need to know what kind of sensors are actually there and most importantly how they need to be initialized and called.

If you ask for a high accuracy, it will try to get the position from the GPS (if present) otherwise it will get the best result as soon as possible (again, it could be the GPS if it was already been used recently and still has a fix on satellites)

Comment: Alright, my problem is that my laptop got no gps antenna, so its supposed to use WIFI automatically right? But I guess it doesn't do so since the result in Longitude and Latitude is always "NaN". Can you help me on this?

Comment: Do you have an example of how you use that class ? I just tried on my machine (no GPS, only WiFi) and it works. Here https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher(v=vs.110).aspx you can find a simple program. I changed the timeout from 1000 to 10000 to allow additional time